# admobで 同じページ複数の広告を表示させる方法教えてください。

Tags: android, java, admob

Androidアプリの質問です。

admob で、同じページ複数の広告を表示させる方法教えてください。

１つの広告は表示できました。

よろしくお願いいたします

---

２ページ目にも　表示出来ないのですが

どうすれば良いでしょうか？

Comment: ソースコードがなければアドバイスのしようがないと思います。広告が表示できた部分、表示できない2ページ目の部分のコードを提示してください。

Answer (score 6):

AdMobのポリシーを確認してください。
1ページに表示できる広告は1つまでです。
https://support.google.com/admob/answer/2753860#ad_placement